Where to find extract code suggestion setting in IntelliJ
Where can I find the extract code suggestions settings in intelliJ?
sometimes it gives me suggestions for extracting long codes to several private methods, and I clicked something like 'no more suggestions for this length of code', where I could give the minimum length for those kind of suggestions.
And I want to reset the setting, but can't find out where it was.
(I haven't turned on the sync setting so I can't really find the changed setting either)
Can someone help me with this?
Thank you!

Please try to restore inspections profile to defaults ("Settings | Editor | Inspections")

It is probably the Java | Code maturity | Method can be extracted inspection. You can find it under Preferences | Editor | Inspections.
